# Remove the repeated column names in R

Tags: r

I have a large data set but the heading columns are repeated like this:

```html
 ipad1 ipad2 ipad3
Time1 12 14 16
 ipad1 ipad2 ipad3
Time2 14 19 22
 ipad1 ipad2 ipad3
Time3 78 90 23
```

I want to get rid of of the repeated column names to get like this table:

```html
  ipad1 ipad2 ipad3
Time1     12  14  16
Time2     14  19  22
Time3     78  90  23
```

is there is a simple code to do it?

Comment: Can you show what your input file looks like and how you are trying to read it in?

Comment: I have already shown it . See above

Comment: sorry but i don't see where you show how you are reading in the file.

Comment: Could you post a sample using `dput(head(df, 1))`?

Comment: I agree this is hard to understand as is, a dput output to work with would be useful. However, to remove duplicated columns you can use df[, !duplicated(colnames(df))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter on column named "ipad1" and filter for all that is not "ipad1"

This worked for me when I copied your example data:

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("test.xlsx")

View(df)

col1    ipad1    ipad2   ipad3
Time1   12       14      16
Na      ipad1    ipad2   ipad3
Time2   14       19      22
Na      ipad1    ipad2   ipad3
Time3   78       90      23

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(ipad1 != "ipad1")
```

Output:

```
  col1  ipad1 ipad2 ipad3
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Time1 12    14    16   
2 Time2 14    19    22   
3 Time3 78    90    23
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, it is difficult to determine what you are starting with.

If you have a tab-delimited text file, for example named `ipad_data.txt`, with your data, you could do the following:

```
raw_lines <- readLines(file("ipad_data.txt"))
dat_lines <- paste(raw_lines[c(FALSE, TRUE)], collapse = "\n")
dat <- read.table(text = dat_lines)
names(dat) <- unlist(strsplit(raw_lines[1], split = "\t"))
```

**Output**

```
        ipad1 ipad2 ipad3
1 Time1    12    14    16
2 Time2    14    19    22
3 Time3    78    90    23
```